# How to show pdf file in GridView as thumbnail

Tags: android

I want to show some bunch of pdf file in my android application as GridView. Pdf file should be present as image in gridview as thumbnail. After clicking on that file, view should be generate as sliding navigation from pdf pages. For better understanding i am including two image here. [image: pdf as gridview in thumbnail][image: pdf as navigation]

Any idea will be highly appriciated.

Comment: for 1 you will need to supply a thumbnail for the PDF file and 2 there is no native PDF support in android so you need another app or a third party library to display the PDF file

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to use a 3rd party library and open the pdf for display.  Parsing and displaying PDFs is a time consuming activity.  The usual way of getting around that for displays like this is to pre-render a thumbnail image of the pdf and download that over the net (or have it preinstalled in the apk) and display the pre-rendered thumbnail instead.